# Как написать код для ввода в каждой строке моей матрицы первого по порядку элемента со значением вне заданного интервала [A,B]

Tags: c++, devc++

Я написал код строения матрицы, но не понимаю как написать код который будет искать в каждой строке моей матрицы первого по порядку элемента со значением вне заданного элемента.
#include

```
using namespace std;

int main ()

{
    int n, m[20][20];
    
    cout << "n = ";
    
    cin >> n;
    
    cout << "matrix" << endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
        if(i%2==1)
        
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            
                cin >> m[i][j];
                
        else
        
            for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            
                cin >> m[i][j];
                
    cout<< "matrix" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        
            cout << m[i][j] << "\t";
            
        cout << endl;
    }
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас очень странно заполняется массив - это трудно воспроизвести.
Код поиска элемента вне интервала:

```
int main()

{
    int n=3;

    
    int m[3][3] = { {8,7,5},{8,7,3},{2,8,5} };

    int a = 5;
    int b = 8;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (m[i][j] < a || m[i][j] > b) {
                cout << m[i][j] << endl;
                break;
            }
            if (j == n-1) {
                cout << "Empty" << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    /*
    Empty
    3
    2*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```